# How can I add or remove a logger in logback configuration using logback API

Tags: logging, logback, logback-classic

The purpose is to enable dynamic re-loading of configuration. I know that changing levels is possible.

But, I could not find any method  here [LoggerContext](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/LoggerContext.html) for adding or removing loggers.

For example, in the following logback config file, if I want to add the logger called "chapters.configuration" using an API, how can I do that?

```
 <configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="chapters.configuration" level="INFO"/>

  <!-- Strictly speaking, the level attribute is not necessary since -->
  <!-- the level of the root level is set to DEBUG by default.       -->
  <root level="DEBUG">          
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>  
  
</configuration>
```